# gganimate not showing all frames

Tags: r, animated-gif, gganimate

I'd like to make a simple gif with 138 *states*. I don't need any fancy transitions between each state, but I do need every state to appear in my gif. Currently, [gganimate](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate) is cutting my gif short, not revealing the last ~30ish states.

## Example

```
df <- lapply(1:138, function(t){
  data.frame(
    DT = as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 12:00:00", tz = "UTC") + t*24*60*60,
    x = seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100),
    y = t * seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
  )
})
df <- do.call(rbind, df)
range(df$DT)  # "2019-01-02 12:00:00 UTC" "2019-05-19 12:00:00 UTC"

p <- ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()+ 
  transition_states(states = DT, transition_length = 0, state_length = 1)+
  labs(title = 'ScrapeDT: {previous_state}')
p
```

[image]

As you can see, the gif plays until about 2019-04-10, instead of 2019-05-19. I've also tried tinkering with `animate()` with no success. For example,

```
animate(
  plot = p, 
  nframes = length(unique(df$DT)), 
  fps = 8, 
  end_pause = 8
)
```

[image]

How can I make this work so that **every** desired state is shown for say, 0.25 seconds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://gganimate.com/reference/transition_manual.html), `transition_manual()` is exactly what you need:

> This transition allows you to map a variable in your data to a specific frame in the animation. No tweening of data will be made and the number of frames in the animation will be decided by the number of levels in the frame variable.

Notice what I did below with `transition_manual()` and `labs()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

df <- lapply(1:138, function(t){
  data.frame(
    DT = as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 12:00:00", tz = "UTC") + t * 24 * 60 * 60,
    x = seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100),
    y = t * seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
  )
})
df <- do.call(rbind, df)

p <- ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()+ 
  transition_manual(frames = DT)+
  labs(title = 'ScrapeDT: {current_frame}')

animate(
  plot = p, 
  nframes = length(unique(df$DT)), 
  fps = 4, 
  end_pause = 8
)
```

[image: working-animated-gif]

Comment: Definitely more elegant than increasing `detail`!

Comment: Nice, thank! (Although I would opt for `labs(title = 'ScrapeDT: {current_frame}')`)

Comment: oml, thank you @Ben! I did an entire project not knowing the syntax for that lol. Editing my answer, and I will definitely be using `current_frame` more ;).

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are getting bitten by the frame sampling. From `?animate`:

> The length and framerate is decided on render time and can be any two combination of nframes, fps, and duration.
>
> Rendering is happening in discrete time units. This means that any
>   event in the animation is rounded of to the nearest frame (e.g.
>   entering will always take a whole number of frames). This means that
>   rounding artifacts are possible when only rendering few frames.
>
> To avoid this you can increase the detail argument. detail will get
>   multiplied to nframes and the resulting number of frames will get
>   calculated, but only nframes evenly spaced frames are rendered.

An easy solution to make sure every state is printed is to set `detail` > 1. Typically `detail = fps` will guarantee every frame is used.

```r
animate(
  plot = p, 
  nframes = length(unique(df$DT)), 
  detail = 8,
  fps = 8, 
  end_pause = 8
)
```

[image: with all frames]

Comment: How did you post the animated GIF? And when you tried, did it look like it was a still frame until you posted, or did it show up as animated all along?

Comment: No, I struggled a bit :) I kept pasting a `png` instead of `gif`! You can't copy and paste from the rstudio viewer otherwise you copy one frame. You need to save as `gif` locally (open in new window which opens the gif in browser then `ctrl+s`) then upload the file. It looks animated straight away.

Comment: @Benjamin long ago and you might know this now - easiest is to  use the reprex package - this will automatically create a gif and upload it to imgur