# How to show the current value of y-axis in gganimate?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have a `dataframe` `df`:

```
df = data.frame(name = "bird",
           value = seq(0, 1, length.out = 100),
           step = 1:100)
```

I want to animate this data by showing the variable `value` increasing. In the animation, I want to show the current `step` and `value` for that step.

This is what I have done so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

gg = ggplot(df, aes(name, value)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "darkgreen") +
        coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1))

gg + gganimate::transition_states(step) +
        ggtitle("Step: {closest_state}",
                subtitle = "Value: {frame}")
```

[image]

`step` is shown correctly, but clearly `value` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a similar vein, but without much piping and less computation (simple base R subsetting)

```r
library(gganimate)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
df <- data.frame(
  name = "bird",
  value = seq(0, 1, length.out = 100),
  step = 1:100
)

anim <- ggplot(df, aes(name, value)) +
  geom_col(fill = "darkgreen") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = 0:1) +
  transition_manual(frames = step) +
  ggtitle("Step: {current_frame}",
    subtitle = "Value: {round(df$value[as.integer(current_frame)], 2)}"
  )

animate(anim, duration = 4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

PS I am using `transition_manual` with `current_frame` because gganimate [did not show all frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56447125/gganimate-not-showing-all-frames). Another option would be to use set details = fps in `animate`

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your data by `pull`ing the value for every step like this:

```r
df = data.frame(name = "bird",
                value = seq(0, 1, length.out = 100),
                step = 1:100)

library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.2
library(gganimate)
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

gg = ggplot(df, aes(name, value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "darkgreen") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1))

gg + transition_states(step) +
  ggtitle("Step: {closest_state}",
          subtitle = "Value: {filter(df, step == closest_state) %>% pull(value) %>% .[[1]] %>% round(., 2)}")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>